# create a shell wrapper script to run a python file

Tags: python, shell

I'm having problems when creating a shell wrapper script to be able to run a python file through my terminal. I'm using this as my wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
python3 -u index.py "$@"
```

And I get this error:

```
File "/mnt/c/Users/...", line 2
    python3 -u index.py "$@"
               ^^^^^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have granted permissions to both the wrapper and the python file with the following commands:

```
chmod +x dag
chmod u+x index.py
```

I'm trying to do all of this in Windows, in case that is important. And I have python installed and in my PATH so that it's recognized. Any idea?

Comment: I think your shebang line is wrong. It should probably read `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar. Else the script is executed using the python interpreter.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to include `python3` within the shebang and then again on the second line of code. Your script should likely run from bash and call into Python. Is there anything else notable that this wrapper script does? Or does it simply run the command `python3 -u index.py "$@"` ? If the latter, then you're using bash syntax and not python, but you're trying to run the wrapper script in python directly.

Comment: @h0r53 I want the second option that you said. I want to run a python script using this shell. You also agree with Rafael to remove the python3 from the first line and add the bash?

Comment: @Raphael it was your answer. If you want, post an answer and I set it as the final answer for the question!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a site for *specific* questions, so what exactly do you need help with? To start, do you understand what the error message is saying? Why do you think you're getting that error? See [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: @Alejandro Glad it worked, I added an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your shebang line is wrong.
It should probably read `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar.
Else the script is executed using the python interpreter instead of the shell.